# python pandas groupby and filter function to remove candidates' name without two prediction

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, pandas-groupby

The question is to use Pandas, remove any invalid names and any candidate without both predictions. In the data frame, some candidate names appear twice for two prediction dates or some candidate names only appear once. So I want to drop those candidates who only have one prediction date.

I am trying to use groupby and filter function to drop the candidates' names that doesn't meet both condition: ('forecast_date'== '2018-08-11') AND ('forecast_date'=='2018-11-06')

Here is my code:

```
election_sub=election_sub.dropna(subset=['candidate'])
election_sub.groupby('candidate')
grouped.filter(lambda x: (x['forecast_date']== '2018-08-11')&(x['forecast_date']=='2018-11-06'))
```

Here is the dataframe:
[image: dataframe]

Comment: Hey Yi!!  avoid attaching the image. Rather type it down in your question itself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Super, can you create some sample data, 10 rows with `candidate` and `forecast_date`s only (another columns are not important) and some 3 groups for see which group has to be removed.

Comment: @YiShen - I cannot copy data, because picture. Is possible create data sample like text?

Comment: @jezrael This is the code to download the data: !wget -nc https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/checking-our-work-data/master/us_house_elections.csv

Comment: @YiShen - OK, so if run my data how is possible check expected output? what candidate has to be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#data to DataFrame
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/checking-our-work-data/master/us_house_elections.csv'
election_sub = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['election_date','forecast_date'])
```

---

```
#filter out `NaN`s
election_sub=election_sub.dropna(subset=['candidate'])

#filter rows for match one OR another datetime
df = election_sub[election_sub['forecast_date'].isin(['2018-08-11','2018-11-06'])].copy()
#get number of unique datetimes per groups
s = df.groupby('candidate')['forecast_date'].nunique()
#filter candidates only with both datetimes, like condition AND
cand = s.index[s.eq(2)].unique()
print (cand)

Index(['A. Donald McEachin', 'Aaron Andrus', 'Aaron Swisher',
       'Abby Finkenauer', 'Abigail Spanberger', 'Adam B. Schiff',
       'Adam Kinzinger', 'Adam Smith', 'Adrian Smith', 'Adriano Espaillat',
       ...
       'William Lacy Clay', 'William Tanoos', 'William Timmons',
       'Willie Billups', 'Xochitl Torres Small', 'Young Kim', 'Yvette Clarke',
       'Yvette Herrell', 'Yvonne Hayes Hinson', 'Zoe Lofgren'],
      dtype='object', name='candidate', length=960)

#filter original data by candidates
df = election_sub[election_sub['candidate'].isin(cand)]
```

Your solution is possible with test if at least one condition True for both - output are 2 scalars, so for `AND` is used `and`:

```
grouped = election_sub.groupby('candidate')
df = grouped.filter(lambda x: (x['forecast_date']== '2018-08-11').any() and (x['forecast_date']=='2018-11-06').any())
```

---

```
print(df)
        year office state  district special election_date forecast_date  \
0       2018  House    WY       1.0   False    2018-11-06    2018-11-06   
1       2018  House    WY       1.0   False    2018-11-06    2018-11-06   
2       2018  House    WY       1.0   False    2018-11-06    2018-11-06   
3       2018  House    WY       1.0   False    2018-11-06    2018-11-06   
4       2018  House    WY       1.0   False    2018-11-06    2018-11-06   
...      ...    ...   ...       ...     ...           ...           ...   
282688  2018  House    AK       1.0   False    2018-11-06    2018-08-01   
282689  2018  House    AK       1.0   False    2018-11-06    2018-08-01   
282690  2018  House    AK       1.0   False    2018-11-06    2018-08-01   
282691  2018  House    AK       1.0   False    2018-11-06    2018-08-01   
282692  2018  House    AK       1.0   False    2018-11-06    2018-08-01   

       forecast_type party        candidate  projected_voteshare  \
0               lite     D      Greg Hunter             33.29836   
1               lite     R       Liz Cheney             61.18835   
2             deluxe     D      Greg Hunter             31.37998   
3             deluxe     R       Liz Cheney             63.10673   
4            classic     D      Greg Hunter             31.33293   
...              ...   ...              ...                  ...   
282688          lite     R        Don Young             50.74973   
282689        deluxe     D  Alyse S. Galvin             41.49152   
282690        deluxe     R        Don Young             51.96705   
282691       classic     D  Alyse S. Galvin             44.10701   
282692       classic     R        Don Young             49.35155   

        actual_voteshare  probwin  probwin_outcome  
0                    NaN  0.00134                0  
1                    NaN  0.99866                1  
2                    NaN  0.00020                0  
3                    NaN  0.99980                1  
4                    NaN  0.00032                0  
...                  ...      ...              ...  
282688               NaN  0.76900                1  
282689               NaN  0.12776                0  
282690               NaN  0.87224                1  
282691               NaN  0.28146                0  
282692               NaN  0.71854                1  

[282240 rows x 14 columns]
```

EDIT:

Performance of both solutions is different:

```
In [41]: %%timeit
    ...: df = election_sub[election_sub['forecast_date'].isin(['2018-08-11','2018-11-06'])].copy()
    ...: #get number of unique datetimes per groups
    ...: s = df.groupby('candidate')['forecast_date'].nunique()
    ...: #filter candidates only with both datetimes, like condition AND
    ...: cand = s.index[s.eq(2)].unique()
    ...: 
    ...: #filter original data by candidates
    ...: df = election_sub[election_sub['candidate'].isin(cand)]
    ...: 
61.3 ms ± 180 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [42]: %%timeit
    ...: grouped = election_sub.groupby('candidate')
    ...: df = grouped.filter(lambda x: (x['forecast_date']== '2018-08-11').any() and (x['forecast_date']=='2018-11-06').any())
    ...: 
1.07 s ± 5.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me! The question is to use Pandas, remove any invalid names and any candidate without both predictions. In the data frame, some candidate names appear twice for two prediction dates or some candidate names only appear once. So I want to drop those candidates who only have one prediction date.